# Ajax in rails using post() without serialize()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using this code to make an ajax request in my rails app, I got it from the railscast episode 136.

```
$(this).submit(function() {
$.post(this.attr("action") + ".js", $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
})
```

But I would like to pass data without using serialize. Like:

```
$(this).submit(function() {
$.post(this.attr("action") + ".js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, null, "script");
return false;
})
```

Looking at the examples in the jquery .post documentation it should work, but when I raise params.inspect in my action I don't get those parameters. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I added my form code. But the input fields in the form shouldn't matter if I'm passing in the data without serialize. The editTransaction() function contains the code above.

```
<%= form_tag("edit", :method => "post", :onsubmit => "editTransaction()", :remote => true) do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:id, transaction.id) %>
<%= submit_tag("edit") %>
<% end %>
```

As a temporary fix I added hidden input fields to the form and I update those fields onsubmit with javascript, then I use serialize().

Comment: Are you getting an `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error?

Comment: Nope. The authenticity token is fine.

Comment: Does the first one work?

Comment: Does the form only has 2 fields?